# How do I show that Lκ = Vκ?

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to show that Lκ is a model of ZFC if κ is weakly inaccessible. How do I show that Lκ = Vκ? Since we know Vκ is a model of ZFC I believe this is all I have left to show that Lκ is a model.

Comment: Why would $ V_\kappa=L_\kappa$? For all you know, there are reals not in $ L $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer suggests a direct attack, and that is probably the way you want to go with this. But as you already know that $V_\kappa$ is a model of ZFC if $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible, there is a sneakier way.

We can argue that if $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible then it is (strongly) inaccessible in $L$. It then follows by the fact you stated that $V_\kappa^L$ is a model of ZFC. So the only thing we have to prove is that $L_\kappa=V_\kappa^L$. That this is true follows from two facts:

- $V_\lambda=H_\lambda$ if $\lambda$ is inaccessible. We can apply this to $\kappa$ in $L$ to obtain $V_\kappa^L=H_\kappa^L$.
- $H_\lambda^L=L_\lambda$ for any regular $\lambda$. This follows from the usual condensation argument that proves that GCH holds in $L$.

Putting these two facts together gives us that $L_\kappa=V^L_\kappa$, which is a model of ZFC.

Comment: Thanks! This was the approach I was going for.

Answer (score 2):

$L_\kappa$ need not be $V_\kappa$, so this approach won't work.

What you're trying to show is that $L_\kappa$ is a model of $ZFC$. The right way to prove this is by a direct attack: for each $ZFC$ axiom, show that that axiom is true in $L_\kappa$!

For example, powerset: suppose $A\in L_\kappa$ with $\kappa$ an inaccessible. Then $A\in L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha<\kappa$, since inaccessibles are limit cardinals. By condensation, if $B\in L$ is a subset of $A$, then $B\in L_\beta$, where $\beta=(\alpha^+)^L$ is the successor cardinal of $\alpha$ as computed in $L$.

Since $\alpha<\kappa$ and $\kappa$ is inaccessible (note that if $\kappa$ is inaccessible in reality, then it is also inaccessible relative to $L$), we must have $(\alpha^+)^L+1<\kappa$. But since $\mathcal{P}(A)\cap L\subseteq L_{(\alpha^+)^L}$, we have $\mathcal{P}(A)\cap L\in L_{(\alpha^+)^L+1<\kappa}\subseteq L_\kappa$. So $\mathcal{P}(A)\cap L\in L_\kappa$, and - in $L_\kappa$ - is the powerset of $A$.

So $L_\kappa\models$ Powerset.

One has to similarly argue for each axiom. Note that for powerset, all we've used is that $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal, not an inaccessible; the full strength of inaccessibility only shows up in the proof that Replacement holds in $L_\kappa$.